# Why was there no extensive background check on the said person in 'Goodachari'?

Tags: plot-explanation, goodachari

In *[Goodachari](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7758160/)*, Trinethra knew when Arjun flirted with a girl at the bar and other personal details about him which are surprising.

It should seem little suspicious that [spoiler below]

> A new girl, Sameera is in tow with their newest recruit all of a sudden. Why didn't more information surface about Sameera when Vennela Kishore[Shyam] did a background check on Sameera?

Shouldn't this kind of information be accessible to Trinethra?